# For Loop 'index error: out of range', when it is most certainly not out of range (webscraping bs4)

Tags: python, xpath

I am scraping a web page, using xpath.

this is the xpath:

`"/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/article/div[1]/div[2]/div"`

this returns the 1st price, of the 1st item on the list.

to get the 2nd item the on the list, everything is the same - except `/li[2]/`. ex:

`"/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/article/div[1]/div[2]/div"`

(this is all in a print function, which if printed manually goes up to /`li[41]`/, 41st item)

so I made a while loop:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import requests

URL="https://www.zillow.com/losangeles-ca/"

HEADERS="will need to add in comment, below"

webpage = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")

dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))

x = 1

while x < 41:

    print(dom.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li['+str(x)+']/article/div[1]/div[2]/div')[0].text)
    
    x+=1
```

PLEASE try this out in your ide.

now this will return the 1st 2 items, then throws that error. whereas if manually I can use that exact same format and print every item to the 41st.

Please help, why is this the case???

*** Also, I tried with a For Loop (I have to add a weird Continue statement and it will then print until the 10th item)...

'''
z=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41]

for x in z:

```
if x == 3:

    continue

print(dom.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li['+str(x)+']/article/div[1]/div[2]/div')[0].text)
```

'''

Comment: You would be better off creating the xpath yourself rather than using one generated by dev tools.  Using the [include] syntax and relative paths it makes the xpaths much more flexible and easier to understand.

Comment: It's difficult to know what the problem is without seeing the html, but `li[41]`  would the the 42nd item not the 41st.  indexing always includes 0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: it starts at /li[1]/ weirdly but yeah I thought of that.

Comment: ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 \
            (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',\
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})

Comment: ^^^ above is the headers used.

Comment: `[i.text for i in soup.select('.list-card-price')]`